# How to set data within VueJS lifecycle hook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am attempting to use the `created` lifecycle hook to set a data property on my component. Below is my single-file component. I'm currently seeing `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'summary' of undefined"` in the console when running this code. This tells me that the template is working with `forecastData` as the empty object declared in the `data` property rather than the populated object from `created`. When I remove the `data` property entirely I see `TypeError: Cannot read property 'currently' of undefined`. Clearly, I'm missing something basic here.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      <router-link to="/">Back to places</router-link>
    </p>
    <h2>{{forecastData.currently.summary}}</h2>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'forecast' }">Forecast</router-link>
    <router-link :to="{ name: 'alerts' }">Alerts</router-link>
    <hr>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CurrentWeather',
    data () {
      return {
        forecastData: {}
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      this.$http.get('/api/forecast/boston').then((response) => {
        this.forecastData = response.data;
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
    }
  }
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting the data asynchronously so it doesn't exist when the object is first mounted. When you try to access `forecastData.currently.summary` the `currently` property is undefined, which results in your error.

Use a `v-if` to avoid the error.

```
<h2 v-if="forecastData.currently">{{forecastData.currently.summary}}</h2>
```

Alternatively, define a null summary in your initialization.

```
data () {
  return {
    forecastData: {
        summary: null
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks! Updated to `forecastData: {currently: {summary: null}}` and it works. Is this the proper way to fetch and set data asynchronously when a component is created?

Comment: @MattDionis What you're doing is perfectly fine, you just need to be careful about nested properties that may not exist when the component is initially mounted.